# Entity Framework не подключается к PostgreSQL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Установил пак `EntityFramework6.Npgsql`

Поменял `ConnectionString` в файле `Web.config`

Добавил провайдера PostgreSQL... в общем сделал все, как предложено здесь https://gist.github.com/raspi/8927531

Но при попытке создать в базе таблицу из модели EF, вылазит окно с предложением подключиться к базе. Оно бы и ладно, но среди перечисленных провайдеров PostgreSQL там нет. Посоветуйте что делать. Если я предоставил недостаточно информации, скажите что нужно.

Comment: А у тебя на ПК стоит драйвер для работы с PostgreSQL?

Comment: @iluxa1810, можно подробнее? Ну саму СУБД я установил...

Answer (score 0):

На английском [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14379288/unable-to-create-database-in-postresql-using-npgsql-and-entity-framework-code-fi) написано, что нельзя создать базу данных из Code First и нужно ее делать ручками.

Comment: К сожалению не решило. :(

Comment: @PavelMayorov, я сначала рекомендовал драйвер попробовать поставить. Но это не помогло и я отредактировал свой вопрос. Его коммент к первому варианту ответа.

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, так я в качестве пруфа приложил ссылку, а общую суть ответа скопировал в ответ , что типа нет такого функционала.

Comment: Ну ладно, допустим, базу создать нельзя, но почему моя строка подключения в web.config не работает? Приложение mvc создается не пустое, там есть какая то база и строка подключения к ней. По идее, заменив строку подключения и запустив, я должен был получить исключение с СУБД, а вместо этого получаю исключение, что нет такого провайдера. И да, в том ответе, ссылку на который вы дали, используется старая версия библиотек, и самый последний комментарий в этом ответе гласит, что в новых версиях все норм. А у меня новейшие версии.

Comment: Попробуйте воспользоватся этим компонентом PostgreSQL dotConnect Express for PostgreSQL